# apt hashes error in Debian 12 Bookworm with cdrom

Tags: debian, apt, hashsum

I just installed Debian 12 Bookworm for the first time.

apt will not install gparted. There is a hashes mismatch error :

```
$ sudo apt install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gparted-common
Suggested packages:
  dmraid gpart jfsutils kpartx mtools reiser4progs reiserfsprogs udftools xfsprogs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gparted gparted-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2542 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8724 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 file:/media/debian-disc bookworm/main amd64 gparted-common all 1.3.1-1 [1711 kB]
Err:1 file:/media/debian-disc bookworm/main amd64 gparted-common all 1.3.1-1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:448c2a1c439a2526123c661025fadc190b5a9c561d23d2e6c44264118fe184b7
   - MD5Sum:5fdcf4d3c2272fa5fc9affe8ccd77786 [weak]
   - Filesize:1711028 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
  Last modification reported: Tue, 08 Feb 2022 22:12:15 +0000
Get:2 file:/media/debian-disc bookworm/main amd64 gparted amd64 1.3.1-1 [831 kB]
Err:2 file:/media/debian-disc bookworm/main amd64 gparted amd64 1.3.1-1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:41d45a07fa0e79a9e135da38220bdd124bd09c370029e21ca1e4853b6579a538
   - MD5Sum:4977aac4bd411819c5d4ea6d979eaabc [weak]
   - Filesize:831132 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
  Last modification reported: Tue, 08 Feb 2022 22:12:13 +0000
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
```

I was able to fix that by commenting out the first line in sources.list being the cdrom line. So it is happy to fetch gparted from the net but does not like to take it from the cd. That seems a bit wasteful, especially for a legacy package like gparted. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> That seems a bit wasteful, especially for a legacy package like gparted. Any ideas how to fix this?

What the error is telling you that the file that was read from CDROM was not what it was supposed to be – so, probable, there was data corruption while writing or reading the disk.

So, not really anything to fix, other than to make sure you've downloaded a fresh CDROM image, that its checksum is correct, and that the CDROM's checksum after burning is also correct.

Comment: Oh no - I checked the .iso after downloading and it was correct. The same .iso is saved to the local machine here and mounted and `sudo sha256sum /dev/loop0` returns a possibly unfamiliar hash `edb7f33fd0095519b6b44d9ab3438f4e12b4c572512406453893f9ef436309b3` will keep double checking but maybe this is the first time I have been victim of a MITM attack.

Comment: no, you haven't. The downloaded is was correct.